# Page Speed Taking time to load due to php looping and exporting data

Tags: php, wordpress, performance

I have an interactive map application I am building and the database is relatively small at about 11mb. However it has a lot of rows of data the require me to go through sort them into counties and years.

My page load speeds are about 10-11 seconds trying to go through all of this data and get it organized so that I can then load it with a javascript library called mapael.

I need some help trying to get the page load speeds faster if there is any way to do that. The query doesn't really seem to be the problem. It's more the going through the data that I believe is causing the problem.

```
 <?php
$mydb = new wpdb('uofimap_data','ob2UoV2X5tNz','uofimap_data','localhost');
$data = $mydb->get_results('
                            SELECT state,county,ship_date,total_cost, quantity FROM data
                            ORDER BY county ASC, ship_date ASC
                       ');
$dataArray = array(
        2006 => '',
        2007 => '',
        2008 => '',
        2009 => '',
        2010 => '',
        2011 => '',
        2012 => '',
        2013 => '',
        2014 => '',
);
$prevCounty = null;
$prevState = null;
$prevYear = null;
$countySum = null;
$quantitySum = null;
foreach ($data as $obj) :
    //temp array to push everything into dataArray for year structure and keep all data in tact.
    $tempArray = array();
    //all the information to use for use
    $date = date('Y', strtotime($obj->ship_date));
    $state = $obj->state;
    $county = $obj->county;
    $cost = $obj->total_cost;
    $quantity = $obj->quantity;

    //Print only the needed values which is the sums of that county for that particular year.
    if($prevCounty == $county){
        if($prevYear == $date){
        } else {
            array_push($tempArray, $prevCounty, $prevState, $countySum, $quantitySum);
            $dataArray[$prevYear][] = $tempArray;   
        }
    } else {
        if($prevCounty == null){
            //Only needed if first value in database is a solo county / year. 
            //echo $county . ', ' . $state . ' : ' . $cost . ' ' . $date . ' New Null<br>';
        } else {
            array_push($tempArray, $prevCounty, $prevState, $countySum, $quantitySum);
            $dataArray[$prevYear][] = $tempArray;
        }
    }

    //Set everything 
    if($prevCounty == $county){
        if($prevYear == $date){
            $countySum += $cost;
            $quantitySum += $quantity;
            //echo $county . '  ' . $countySum . '  '. $state . '  ' . $date . ' ' . $quantitySum . ' Previous Year<br>';
        } else {
            $countySum = $cost;
            $quantitySum += $quantity;
            //echo $county . '  ' . $countySum . '  '. $state . '  ' . $date . ' ' . $quantitySum . ' Current Year<br>';
        }
    } else {
        $countySum = $cost;
        $quantitySum = $quantity;
        //echo $county . '  ' . $countySum . '  '. $state . '  ' . $date . ' ' . $quantitySum . ' New County <br>';
    }
    $prevCounty = $county;
    $prevState = $state;
    $prevYear = $date;



endforeach;


$mapaelJson =  '<script type="text/javascript">';
$mapaelJson .= 'data={';
foreach($dataArray as $key => $value){
    $mapaelJson .= '"' . $key . '": {';
    $mapaelJson .= '"areas":{';
    foreach($value as $key1 => $value1){
        $county = $value1[0];
        $county = ucwords(strtolower($county));
        $state = $value1[1];
        $total = $value1[2];
        $quantity = $value[3];

        //var_dump($value1);

        $mapaelJson .= '"'.$county . ', '. $state . '" : {';
            $mapaelJson .= '"county" : "' . $county . '",';
            $mapaelJson .= '"value" : "' . $total . '",';
            $mapaelJson .= '"quantity" : "' . $quantity . '",';
        $mapaelJson .= '},';

    }
    $mapaelJson .= '} },';
}
$mapaelJson .= '};</script>';

echo $mapaelJson;


?>
```

Comment: Look up `json_encode()`

Comment: I would love to just json_encode the information but the javascript library uses it's own object notation and have to write it specifically for it.

Comment: Is there any user-supplied POST or GET data being used by your PHP? If not then set up a scheduled task in which PHP simply creates the HTML/JS (`mapael_json_page.html` or whatever) code needed on this page every 5 minutes or something and change this page to simply be `<?php include('mapael_json_page.html'); ?>`

Comment: If you have a 10 second page load then a sudden influx of users from Reddit or something will crash your site immediately.

Comment: If you don't like my idea then consider not using `array_push()`, it is definitely slower than calling `$tempArray[]` a few times in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into profilers? If you could create traces using the free version of Blackfire.io or cachegrind files using xdebug that would give you the best ideas to optimise.

Anyhow, for the time being you definitely need to reduce the number of loops and inner loops. Also, as much as you can, try having less indentations (keep the number of level low for more readability). You can use `continue` quite often in loops, it generally helps.

Comment: Gave me a great idea of basically just using the spit out code and dumping that into it's own file and not running this php code all the time until I get a new database update. Thanks for the comments on code as well. I have a feeling it is more what stack overflow is doing to my code but never the less thanks. It gave me an idea.

Comment: I am not sure you need to go that far... just a wee profiling might be sufficient to see what can or cannot be optimised. Once you have profiled and optimised, then you can switch to a more complex strategy such as the one you explained. Just throwing a few names here, but basically if it is the way you are looking for, trigger a message on a message broker (RabbitMQ, AmazonSQS, Kafka) when inserting something, and have this queue processed by a script that fetches from database and writes in a key/value database (Redis/Memcached...). That would be faster than your file idea :)